# TravisCI connectedAndroidTest fails

Tags: travis-ci

I am getting the following error on TravisCI:

> The command "./gradlew test connectedAndroidTest" exited with 1.

However, when I run **connectedAndroidTest** gradle task in my local Android Studio, it passes.  So I don't understand why TravisCI wouldn't pass this.  Any ideas?